# Open PDF files, in any subfolder_filename is an number that(know to user) + _v + a number form 1.999

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pdf, subdirectory

I want to make a program that open an PDf

The user know the number but not there the file is or the files complet navn

if the user type 3333

the program might find more the one file

3333_V2.pdf
3333_V3.pdf and so on

the program need to open 3333_V3 in this cause

the files is not in the sames folder

form the main foldes to the files are will in most cases be 2 subfoldes down ( an no rules that want thoes folder is call)

I can´t rule out  that can been 2 files of the same name .. but the files with the same will be the same so it does not matter with one is to be open if just the one with the highest V number

Answer (score 0):

it will be really slow and will make your application very slow if you have one too many files, directories and sub-directories, but you can use something like

```
        string UserInput = "";
        string rootdir = @""; //Your directory path
        // gets list of directories and subdirectories
        var dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(rootdir, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
         
        foreach (var Dir in dirs)
        {
            var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Dir, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (var Fls in files)
            {
                // gets list of all files in directory
                if (Path.GetExtension(Fls) == ".pdf" && Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Fls).StartsWith(UserInput))
                    Process.Start(Fls);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I get an error in the code ... where thes Process come ?

Comment: try using `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Fls).CONTAINS(UserInput)` insted of `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Fls).StartsWith(UserInput)` may be that will help...

Comment: I use the same code to register DLL on a custom H/W running in a network